# Cannot connect Strongloop / Loopback datasource to a SQL Server Express database

Tags: sql-server, loopbackjs, strongloop

Within a newly created loopback framework running `slc arc` I am attempting to connect to an existing SQL Server Express database at `ALEX\SQLEXPRESS` (I've also tried variations like `LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS`).

But I am getting the error message:

> Oops! Something is wrong
>   Failed to connect to ALEX:undefined in 15000ms

I've also tried `ALEX\\SQLEXPRESS` since it looks like the `undefined` might be caused by the slash.

Unfortunately no luck. Does anyone know how to make this work?

These are the settings

[image: the settings]

This is the connector that gets created in the folders:

```
{
  "db": {
  "name": "db",
  "connector": "memory"
  },
  "mssql": {
    "host": "ALEX\\SQLEXPRESS",
    "database": "bbdb-dev",
    "password": "********",
    "name": "mssql",
    "user": "sa",
    "connector": "mssql"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the full connection string (if you have one)?

Comment: added connector and settings screenshot (password obfuscated)

Comment: Do you perhaps need to specify the port number too?

Comment: no - it looks to default port (1433).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the SQL server must be configured correctly I used these instructions http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/ and then connected via IP address instead of a named connection with a slash in it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that SQL server is configured correctly.

Install connector globally `sudo npm install loopback-connector-mssql -g`

Give in the credentials in Arc. refer screen-shot to see how I've connected

[image]

Hope it helps! Works for me :)